# Aggregating or Bundle a Many to Many Relationship in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, join, many-to-many, recursive-query

So I have 1 single table with 2 columns : Sales_Order called `ccso`, Arrangement called `arrmap`
The table has distinct values for this combination and both these fields have a Many to Many relationship

- 1 `ccso` can have Multiple `arrmap`
- 1 `arrmap` can have Multiple `ccso`

All such combinations should be considered as one single bundle

**Objective :**
Assign a final map to each of the Sales Order as the Largest Arrangement in that Bundle

**Example:**
ccso : 100-10015 has 3 arrangements --> Now each of those arrangements have a set of Sales Orders --> Now those sales orders will also have a list of other arrangements and so on
(Image : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGNyr.png))

Therefore the answer definitely points to something recursively checking. Ive managed to write the below code / codes and they work as long as I hard code a ccso in the where clause - But I don't know how to proceed after this now. (I'm an accountant by profession but finding more passion in coding recently) I've searched the forums and web for things like

- Recursive CTEs,
- many to many aggregation
- cartesian product etc
  and I'm sure there must be a term for this which I don't know yet. I've also tried
  I have to use sqldeveloper or googlesheet query and filter formulas
  sqldeveloper has restrictions on on some CTEs. If recursive is the way I'd like to know how and if I can control the depth to say 4 or 5 iterations

Ideally I'd want to update a third column with the final map if possible but if not, then a select query result is just fine

**Codes I've tried**

**Code 1: As per Screenshot**

```
    WITH    a1(ccso, amap) AS 
            (SELECT  distinct a.ccso, a.arrmap
            FROM    rg_consol_map2 A
            WHERE   a.ccso = '100-10115' -- this condition defines the ultimate ancestors in your chain, change it as appropriate
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  m.ccso, m.arrmap
            FROM    rg_consol_map2 m
            JOIN    a1
            ON      M.arrmap = a1.amap --  or m.ccso=a1.ccso
            ) /*if*/ CYCLE amap SET nemap TO 1 /*else*/ DEFAULT 0 
SELECT DISTINCT amap FROM (SELECT ccso, amap FROM a1 ORDER BY 1 DESC) WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

In this the main challenge is how to remove the hardcoded ccso and do a join for each of the ccso

**Code 2 : Manual CTEs for depth**
Here again the join outside the CTE gives me an error and sqldeveloper does not allow WITH clause with UPDATE statement - only works for select and cannot be enclosed within brackets as subtable

```
SELECT distinct ccso FROM
(
WITH ar1 AS
(SELECT distinct arrmap
FROM rg_consol_map
WHERE ccso = a.ccso
)
,so1 AS
(SELECT DISTINCT ccso
FROM rg_consol_map
WHERE arrmap IN (SELECT arrmap FROM ar1)
)
,ar2 AS
(SELECT DISTINCT ccso FROM rg_consol_map
where arrmap IN (select distinct arrmap FROM rg_consol_map
WHERE ccso IN (SELECT ccso FROM so1)
))
SELECT ar1.arrmap, NULL ccso FROM ar1
union all
SELECT null, ar2.ccso FROM ar2
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL arrmap, so1.ccso FROM so1
)
```

Am I Missing something here or is there an easier way to do this? I read something about MERGE and PROC SQL JOIN but was unable to get them to work but if that's the way to go ahead I will try further if someone can point me in the direction
(Image : [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bcT1.png))

(CSV File : [3])

Edit : Fixing CSV file link
https://github.com/karan360note/karanstackoverflow.git
I suppose can be downloaded from here **IC mapping many to many.csv**

Oracle 11g version is being used
[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: The CSV file is not downloading; if it is at all possible to modify the existing database with any kind of "isParent"/"hasChildren" flag, recursive CTE would be simplified. As it is, I'm testing out something now; I know SQL Server has a recursive limitation, and I'm sure Oracle does too. Confirming you're using Oracle would help; SQL Developer technically works with several different types of databases.

Comment: tagged. it is Oracle 11g
@CoffeeNeedCoffee - added correct csv link from github and using Oracle. There is not parent child flag or relationship here. I currently have a long drawn process on excel with pivot tables and counts if that is required to explain

Comment: @CoffeeNeedCoffee If I misunderstood your question about parent child - Yes the tables / database can be modified but there is no such information in the source of this data or anywhere. It is upto this activity to assign a particular arrangement to it. Alternatively the bundles can also be assigned an integer in sequence if that is easier to populate as well.
It is unfrotunately jumbled jigsaw but it does end after 5 to 6 iterations / recursions (atleast on excel)

Answer (score 1):

Apologies in advance for the wall of text.

Your problem is a complex, multi-layered Many-to-Many query; there is no "easy" solution to this, because that is not a terribly ideal design choice. The safest best does literally include multiple layers of CTE or subqueries in order to achieve all the depths you want, as the only ways I know to do so recursively rely on an anchor column (like "parentID") to direct the recursion in a linear fashion. We don't have that option here; we'd go in circles without a way to track our path.

Therefore, I went basic, and with several subqueries. Every level checks for a) All orders containing a particular ARRMAP item, and then b) All additional items on those orders. It's clear enough for you to see the logic and modify to your needs. It will generate a new table that contains the original CCSO, the linking ARRMAP, and the related CCSO. Link: https://pastebin.com/un70JnpA

This should enable you to go back and perform the desired updates you want, based on order # or order date, etc... in a much more straightforward fashion. Once you have an anchor column, a CTE in the future is much more trivial (just search for "CTE recursion tree hierarchy").

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CCSO, RELATEDORDER
FROM myTempTable
WHERE CCSO = '100-10115';     /* to find all orders by CCSO, query SELECT DISTINCT RELATEDORDER */
--WHERE ARRMAP = 'ARR10524';  /* to find all orders by ARRMAP, query SELECT DISTINCT CCSO */
```

EDIT:

To better explain what this table generates, let me simplify the problem.

If you have order

- A with arrangements 1 and 2;
- B with arrangement 2, 3; and
- C with arrangement 3;

then, by your initial inquiry and image, order A should related to orders B and C, right? The query generates the following table when you SELECT DISTINCT ccso, relatedOrder:

```
+-------+--------------+
|  CCSO | RelatedOrder |
+----------------------+
|   A   |     B        |
|   A   |     C        |
+----------------------+
|   B   |     C        |
|   B   |     A        |
+----------------------+
|   C   |     A        |
|   C   |     B        |
+-------+--------------+
```

You can see here if you query `WHERE CCSO = 'A' OR RelatedOrder = 'A'`, you'll get the same relationships, just flipped between the two columns.

```
+-------+--------------+
|  CCSO | RelatedOrder |
+----------------------+
|   A   |     B        |
|   A   |     C        |
+----------------------+
|   B   |     A        |
+----------------------+
|   C   |     A        |
+-------+--------------+
```

So query only CCSO or RelatedOrder.

As for the results of `WHERE CCSO = '100-10115'`, see image [here](https://pasteboard.co/JAdp2aI.png), which includes all the links you showed in your Image #1, as well as additional depths of relations.

Comment: Ok so the query you sent does run - but the results don't help with this.. If you run the below, you can see that they don't have any common value that I should use `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM mytemptable where ccso = '100-10115' or relatedorder = '100-10115'`
1. If the issue is to control the recursion without an anchor, can something like this be used? `OPTION(MAXRECUSRION 1000)` https://stackoverflow.com/a/52552847/9866887

2. Or a Counter
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35151751/9866887

3. Or SAS / sqlproc?
https://www.listendata.com/2015/12/sas-many-to-many-merge.html?m=1

Comment: I will say that the table will you give duplicate results if you query ```where ccso = '100-10115' or relatedorder = '100-10115'```; you should only query **one** of those columns to see all its relations, or it'll give you twice the results, merely flipped. I'll try to update the answer to display why. Sort the query by CCSO, RelatedOrder, then ARRMAP to see what I mean.

Comment: As for the results not being what you want, I don't understand; every one of those are precisely related as your example image 1. You wanted to see all of its relations regardless of path, but you didn't specify you wanted to see the exact path of their relations; this query will not give you the explicit path it found. MAX RECURSION does not help because you have no linear direction to query through, so it will literally loop in circles if you try a CTE.